# Hide url in subdirectory install? (drupal)

Tags: drupal-7, directory

in my site I use version 7 of Drupal and Linux OS on the server, and need to hide the subdirectory of the installation when access by LINK ...

explaining better: Current link: [example.com/folder](http://www.example.com) I want to change for only: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
I searched in various forums, websites and how is an old subject, I believe that there was a change in the code to hide / delete the symbolic url paste ... In the folder / root .htaccess I created left like this:

`Options + FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Folder / $ 1 [L]`

Thus, to access the site, only the index remains without the folder ... I want the whole site be without referencing the subfolder where it was installed ... How do I do this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please look into changing your $base_url in your settings.php file and then you may need to change the re-write rules in .htaccess!

Hope this helps...

Comment: dont work i have tried this, i searched and i found the problem. My host is hostgator plan shared, and dont have permission to rewrite the dir_root, thx

Comment: Hostgator will give you access to settings.php in sites/default/files right? it will also give access to .htacess file right? You couldnt get access to which file sorry